# Resource Monitor - Why are some TCP connections grayed out?

Tags: resource-monitor

When running Resource Monitor on Windows 2008 R2, some TCP connections are grayed out and others are solid black. What does it mean if they are grayed out?

Answer (score 11):

Refer the below link

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/eb6d5598-674a-40f6-a9eb-9f298886b9ce/resource-monitor-tcp-connections

> Grey entries are only shown briefly in Resource Monitor to indicate
>   the TIME_WAIT state has ended and the port is fully released. In
>   short, it's just a helpful breadcrumb that gives you a way to verify
>   that yes, a port has finished the release process.